# Update on SQLALCHEMY for a specifc variable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2

Basically this is not working because I think its looking for a list or something. I need it where the user can update one variable from the record..i.e just want to update the surname of the contact. Is that possible here?

Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app

response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/home/rob/webappan2/addressbook/app.py", line 90, in contact_edit

contact.surname = form.data('surname')

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

My edit method:

```
#edit the contact
@app.route('/edit/<int:contact_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
#GET - Requests data from a specified resource
def contact_edit(contact_id):
        form = ContactsForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            contact = db.session.query(Contact).filter_by(id=contact_id).all()
            contact.surname = form.data('surname')
            contact.firstname =  form.data('firstname')
            contact.email =  form.data('email')
            contact.mobile =  form.data('mobile')
            contact.work_location =  form.data('work_location')
            db.session.commit()
            flash('The contact was successfully edited')
            return redirect(url_for('contact_detail',contact_id=contact_id))
        elif request.method != 'POST':
            contacts=db.session.query(Contact).filter_by(id=contact_id).all()
            return render_template('editcontact.html', contacts=contacts, form=form)
```

With changes:

```
#edit the contact
@app.route('/edit/<int:contact_id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
#GET - Requests data from a specified resource
def contact_edit(contact_id):
   form = ContactsForm(request.POST)
   if form.validate_on_submit():
        contact = db.session.query(Contact).filter_by(id=contact_id).all()
        form.populate_obj(contact)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('The contact was successfully edited')
        return redirect(url_for('contact_detail',contact_id=contact_id))
    else:
        contacts=db.session.query(Contact).filter_by(id=contact_id).all()
        return render_template('editcontact.html', contacts=contacts, form=form)
```

Error after change:

```
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

   return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

   File "/home/rob/webappan2/addressbook/app.py", line 87, in contact_edit

   form = ContactsForm(request.POST)

   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__

   return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)

   AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? If you are getting an error, please share the error and the traceback.

Comment: thanks I should of been more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error tells you, `form.data` is a `dict`, not a callable. To access values in `form.data`, you would use `form.data['surname']`. If you are using WTForms, you'd be better off switching to `form.surname.data`.

There are also some other things you'll need to change before your code will work properly. You'll want to pass the request data to your form. You'll want to change `form = ContactForm()` to `form = ContactForm(request.form)`. Without doing this, all of the values contained by `form` will be blank or the specified default.

After making this change, you'll most likely be able to reduce all of your `contact.X = form.X.data` assignments down to just a single call to`form.populate_obj(contact)`.

Lastly, you'll also want to validate the data. As your code stands, introducing these changes would allow invalid data passed through the form to overwrite what's already stored in the database. (As it stands, your code would overwrite what's in the database with blank/default values.) Inside your `if request.method == 'POST':` you should include a `if form.validate():` check. If you are using Flask-WTF, these two `if`s can be combined into a single `if form.validate_on_submit():`.

P.S. All of the code-specific suggestions assume WTForms.

Comment: Thanks for that although it brings up error when using ContactForm(request.POST)

Comment: I've made the change as you suggested. Yes its WTF-forms

Comment: I fixed the example. It should be `request.form`, not `request.POST`.

Comment: Also, if you switch to Flask-WTF, you can continue to use `form = ContactForm()`. Flask-WTF will read from `request.form` for you.